# Car wont turn on Ford Explore

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission

I have a ford explore 2002 limited edition and the transmission blew out on me but my car wont turn on anymore. Does the transmission have anything to do with my car not turning on?

Comment: Could you elaborate?  What do you mean by "won't turn on"? When you put the key in and turn to "on", do dash lights come on? If you turn key to start, does the engine crank?

Comment: yes so i put in the key and when i try to turn it on nothing happens. The lights don't turn on and the start doesn't make the little click sound I got my battery tested and my battery is good

Comment: The transmission doesn't *directly* affect whether the car might or might not turn on.  Depending on how the tranny blew out, it could have potentially damaged something.  From your description though it really sounds like a dead battery.  Are you sure the connectors are on tightly?  Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair, by the way!

Comment: If not a dead battery, as @Cullub wrote,  it could be the battery cables or connections are somehow defective.